# What does the asterisk mean on the region tooltip?

Tags: hearts-of-iron-3

When in region view, some regions have an asterisk next to their name in the tooltip. Others don't. What does the asterisk indicate? (See screenshot for example).

It doesn't seem to be affected by war - in this game the asterisk was there before I declared war on Greece, and after I had occupied them.

[image: Region view]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It means that the region with the asterisk can be selected as an "acquire territory" wargoal. So, if Japan declares war on the USA and sets their wargoal to acquire the "strategic West Coast cities", then causes the USA to surrender, they will take San Francisco, San Diego, LA, and Seattle, but the USA will keep everything else and the two nations will be at peace.

The regions that can be used with this wargoal are kind of randomly spread out: the USSR is split up into many regions, but only Alaska, their Pacific bases, and the aforementioned cities of the US are compatible with this. Also, for some reason, every region in Greece and Yugoslavia is a demand-able region; as well as certain countries, such as Norway and Greece (again).

Sadly, this wargoal still requires you to take enough victory points for your enemy to surrender - you can't just occupy the provinces that make up the territory you demanded.